# Unable to update record in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Need help in updating records using LinQ.

I tried updating the record, but it does not display in the database.

The primary key is set in both db and LinQ dbml file.

Below are the codes:

```
RPHContrib _phContrib = new RPHContrib();
_phContrib.PHTableNo = phContrib.PHTableNo;
_phContrib.AmountFrom = phContrib.AmountFrom;
_phContrib.AmountTo = phContrib.AmountTo;
_phContrib.EmployeePH = phContrib.EmployeePH;
_phContrib.EmployerAmt = phContrib.EmployerAmt;
_phContrib.IsActive = phContrib.IsActive;
_phContrib.CreatedByNo = phContrib.CreatedByNo;
_phContrib.CreatedDate = phContrib.CreatedDate;
_phContrib.ModifiedByNo = SessionStateController.OnlineUserNo;
_phContrib.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

LINQHelper.Instance.GenericDataContext<HRWizardDataContext>(GetDataContext(false));
LINQHelper.Instance.Update<RPHContrib>(_phContrib);

public bool Update<T>(T obj) where T : class, ICommon, new()
{
    using (var db = GetDBDataContext())
    {    
        db.Connection.Open();
        DbTransaction trans = db.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        db.Transaction = trans;

        // Populate object log                
        obj.IModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

        try
        {
            Detach<T>(obj); // Detach LINQ entity from the original DataContext before attaching to the new one            
            db.GetTable<T>().Attach(obj, true);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            db.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            db.Transaction.Rollback();
            // TODO: Put error logging code here
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (db.Connection != null)
            {
                db.Connection.Close();
                db.Connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this causes your problem but you detach exactly the same object as you attach?

Comment: Try changing the object after you've detached it from the old context and attached it to the new context.

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Profiler to see exactly what is being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding a new recored use `InsertOnSubmit(Entity)`, afterwhich any Auto Numbers (eg. primary) will be updated on your object automatically after you call SubmitChanges().

Use `Attach(Entity)` when you are updating an entity. Make changes to the entity after you have attached it. Making changes before you attach it to the Context will not trigger the Update SQL as the context will think there is nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `insertonsubmit(obj);` before `submitchanges();`